# SwiftUI - Scrollable ListView, Objects Not Rendering Properly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a ScrollView with custom "items", but for some reason each item is rendering stacked up on top of each other.

Here is the method which returns a ScollView containing a VStack of items.

```
private func dailyEventsView(width: CGFloat) -> some View {
        
        var events = dailyData.getEvents()
        
        return ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach (0 ..< events.count) { i in
                    if (events[i].getType() == EventType.WATER) {
                        WaterCardView(event: events[i] as! WaterEvent)
                            .frame(width: width)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here s the "WaterCadView".

```
struct WaterCardView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var event: WaterEvent
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0).fill(Color.gray).opacity(0.05)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    event.getCardViewHeader()

                    // Just a series of progress bars, does not affect output.
                    WaterProgressBar(max: event.max, progress: event.progress, current: event.current)
                        // Height should be same as progress bar thickness
                        .frame(height: 10.0)
                }.padding()
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        .padding(.trailing, 10)
    }
}
```

Here is the output...

[Simulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKFEZ.png)

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have used this method for many Scrollable list views many times, I probably missed something small, but any would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `GeometryReader` without some explicitly set restrictions in any scrollable container, because it confuses SwiftUI layout engine (which you observe).

In your scenario I assume you wanted something like

```
struct WaterCardView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var event: WaterEvent
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            event.getCardViewHeader()

            // Just a series of progress bars, does not affect output.
            WaterProgressBar(max: event.max, progress: event.progress, current: event.current)
                // Height should be same as progress bar thickness
                .frame(height: 10.0)
        }.padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0).fill(Color.gray).opacity(0.05)
        )
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        .padding(.trailing, 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it. Could you please go further in depth as to how exactly GeomtryReader works? I tend to use it often when I need to make sub-views relative to each other, or with some math required relative to frame size.  I am new to SwiftUI, coming over from Android...